# Office 365 Calendar REST API : "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: api, rest, calendar, office365

I've been using the Office 365 Calendar REST api for a few weeks with several users.
I'm currently experiencing something very wierd:
When fetching events of a specific user with the /calendarview call (via OAUTH2). I get perfect results (though very slow), EXCEPT when 25/01 is between my start_date and end_date, I get :

```
{"error":{"code":"ErrorInternalServerError","message":"Object
reference not set to an instance of an object."}}"
```

I suspect one the event of this user is causing this, but still, the API should not bug ?

Any clue?

Here are the instrumented logs:

```
GET /api/v1.0/me/calendars/AQMkAGVmMjlhY2E5LWE4MmMtNGFhAGMtYjY5OC0wNmRiMWYxZDJkM2UARgAAA4ZtZygzpnpGt-RyQ8uQQ80HAG6teJW1hzZBuLm47wZiBYIAAAIBBgAAAG6teJW1hzZBuLm47wZiBYIAAAIM4gAAAA==/calendarview?&startDateTime=2015-02-24T23:55:38Z&endDateTime=2015-02-25T23:55:38Z&$top=50&$skip=0

HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Ruby, JulieDesk
Authorization: Bearer $REFRESHTOKEN$
Return-Client-Request-Id: true
Client-Request-Id: be203946-93b7-47f6-b402-edbd0ed49653
Host: outlook.office365.com

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false;charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
request-id: 4a0fe2ba-a761-4526-bd09-70c81e084cb5
client-request-id: be203946-93b7-47f6-b402-edbd0ed49653
Set-Cookie: ClientId=LSM5BXAUPUIJBVFLY0LDA; expires=Tue, 16-Feb-2016 23:55:39 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
X-CalculatedBETarget: co1pr07mb316.namprd07.prod.outlook.com
OData-Version: 4.0
X-DiagInfo: CO1PR07MB316
X-BEServer: CO1PR07MB316
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Set-Cookie: exchangecookie=7b08adfab00641009c1cbbf90594797d; expires=Tue, 16-Feb-2016 23:55:40 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: X-BackEndCookie2=3bd486f8-787b-435b-8269-5359cdbcc7ce=u56Lnp2ejJqBxsmZysiemc/SyMmazNLLyJvO0sbGxs3Smc+bm87Pz8+dm8aegYHNz87K0s/M0s7Hq83MxcrKxcvJgZGeko+Nm8/I0Y+NkJvRkIqLk5CQlNGckJI=; expires=Wed, 18-Mar-2015 23:55:46 GMT; path=/api; secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: X-BackEndCookie=3bd486f8-787b-435b-8269-5359cdbcc7ce=u56Lnp2ejJqBxsmZysiemc/SyMmazNLLyJvO0sbGxs3Smc+bm87Pz8+dm8aegYHNz87K0s/M0s7Hq83MxcrKxcvJ; expires=Wed, 18-Mar-2015 23:55:46 GMT; path=/api; secure; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-FEServer: DM2PR09CA0014
Date: Mon, 16 Feb 2015 23:55:45 GMT
Content-Length: 111

-> "{\"error\":{\"code\":\"ErrorInternalServerError\",\"message\":\"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.\"}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry about the odd error! I'd definitely like to find out more. Could you add [client instrumentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn720380(v=exchg.150).aspx) to your request, reproduce the error, and let me know the values of the HTTP response headers in that article?

Comment: By investigating with our user, it seems that it might be linked with events from external sources present in the calendar at the times where the request fails. Any clue or update ?

Comment: No, though it would be good to gather examples of these externally-sourced events to see if it can be reproduced. For example, if the user saves the event as an MSG file, and you copy it into a test mailbox, can you reproduce the error? I'd be happy to debug it further if so.

Comment: Is there a way to add this client instrumentation to the SDK?

Comment: Which one? There's a few :)

Comment: The Office 365 SDK, im using the .NET version of it

Comment: Another thing I noticed, is that in the account that is presenting the problems, if I try to edit the meetings in the outlook web app, only appears a blank page... 
We are only able to edit this meetings on outlook desktop

Comment: I too am currently experiencing this issue with the O365 calendar API. Was there any update as to what was causing this?

I'm actually able to make the same calendarview call via the EWS API without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when filtering by Subject where some events didn't have a subject.

I fixed this by including `Subject ne null` in the filter query